# Problem with custom projection in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, proj

I'm using OpenLayers 2 with Proj4JS 1.10. When trying to change the map's projection using

```
Proj4js.defs['STEREOGRAPHIC:180,90'] = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=180 +a=3396190.0 +b=3396190.0 +over=F +geoc=T";
map.baseLayer.projection.proj = new Proj4js.Proj('STEREOGRAPHIC:180,90');
```

and then zooming in to refresh the map, I get a JavaScript error tracing back to the Graticule control: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null`.

Is there an issue with my proj4 string or could this be a bug with OpenLayers or Proj4JS?

Comment: You aren't by chance using geoext with that?

Comment: Not that I know of.